# How to unzip/unpack `.conda` package archive files?

Tags: conda, zstandard

Conda Forge [recently converted](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/announcements.html#moving-to-conda-artifacts) to exclusively emitting `.conda` files for its package builds, instead of `.tar.gz` files. With the tarballs, we could previously use `tar` to unpack the archive.

***How can one unpack the `.conda` archive files?***

---

### Failed attempts

#### gzip

Naively trying `gzip` gives

```bash
$ gzip -d libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda 
gzip: libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

and forcing the suffix with `-S .conda` reports

```bash
$ gzip -d -S .conda libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda 
gzip: libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda: not in gzip format
```

#### zstd

The [blog post introducing the format](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance) mentions **zstandard** compression format, but using `zstd` doesn't seem to fare any better:

```bash
$ zstd -d libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda
zstd: libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda: unknown suffix (.zst/.tzst expected). Can't derive the output file name. Specify it with -o dstFileName. Ignoring.

$ zstd -d -o libtiff libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda 
zstd: libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda: unsupported format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda provides a Python package, `conda-package-handling` (see [documentation](https://conda.github.io/conda-package-handling/)), which comes installed with the **base** environment. This includes a CLI entry point, `cph`, for working with Conda packages. One can extract a `.conda` archive using, for example,

```bash
$ cph extract libtiff-4.5.0-h82bc61c_0.conda
```

---

### Help Message

For reference, here is the help message the tool emits:

```bash
$ cph -h
usage: cph [-h] [-V] {extract,x,create,c,verify,v,transmute,t} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -V, --version         Show the conda-package-handling version number and exit.

subcommands:
  {extract,x,create,c,verify,v,transmute,t}
    extract (x)         extract package contents
    create (c)          bundle files into a package
    verify (v)          verify converted files against their reference
    transmute (t)       convert from one package type to another
```